# test for partial refund in magento email template

Tags: php, magento, templates

I'm working on my refund email template, using CMS block inclusion based on template tests of payment method, like `{{if order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getCode() == "payment_method"}}`. Now to the problem, I also need to check if a credit memo is for the full order or if it's only partial, so that I can include diffrent CMS blocks depening on if the text should say "full refund" or "partial refund".  Any idea how I could check for partial vs full refunds in the email template?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the template logic isn't advanced enought to do what I need. I managed to include a block from the template instead, which contains the logic and loads sub-templates depending on result. To check for full refund vs partial, I checked with `$order->canCreditmemo()`. This will return false if it's not possible to add another credit memo, which you obviously can't do on an already fully refunded order.